# How to make a loop check off only one item at a time using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am building a simple todo list, but I am having a bit of trouble for about 2 weeks now trying to solve this problem I have with the loops. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong please? I want to check each item off one at a time, I'm currently using for loops to iterate thru each item. The problem I have been facing is that the loops cause all items to be checked off at the same time. I have tried simple if else statements, switches, while loops, nested for loops. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Code below.

Javascript

```
const check = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
const uncheck = document.querySelectorAll('.uncheck');
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

function checkItem(event) {
    for(let i = 0; i < li.length && i < check.length && i < uncheck.length; i++) {

        switch(event.target.classList.contains('far')) {
            case true:
                li[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
                check[i].style.display = 'block';
                uncheck[i].classList.toggle('check');
                break;
            default:
                li[i].style.textDecoration = 'none';
                check[i].style.display = 'none';
                uncheck[i].classList.toggle('uncheck');
        }
    }
}
```

EJS

```
    <body onclick="checkItem(event)">

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="interface">
                <header>
                    <i class="fas fa-sync-alt" id="delAllBtn"></i>
                    <div id="datebox">
                          <p id="time">4:20pm</p>
                          <br>
                          <p id="date">September 24, 2020</p>  
                    </div>
                </header>
        
                <div id="userInput">
                    <form action="/list" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter item.." name="item" autofocus required> 
                        <button type="submit" id="addBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
                    </form>    
                </div>
        
                <main>
                    <ul id="list">
                        <% for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {%>
                            <li class="list-item">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <i class="far fa-circle uncheck"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle check"></i>
                                </div>
                                <span><%= list[i].item %></span>
                                <div id="buttons">
                                    <button type="submit" data-update="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" data-update="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="editBtn"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" data-delete="<%= list[i]._id %>" class="delItemBtn"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>   
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <% } %>
                    </ul>    
                </main>
        
                <footer>
                    <p>Footer</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have answered your own question here, all items are being checked off because you are using a for loop. Try using e.target after defining a function that you want to call after a click event. This way you will only change the individual item that you click on:

```
    function checkItem(el) {   
            if (el.classList.contains('uncheck')) {
                el.classList.add("check");
                el.classList.remove("uncheck");
            }
        }

    document.querySelector('#list').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            checkItem(e.target);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating event.target on every iteration of the for loop.

You should do it based on the current element of the iteration so that each element gets updated based on its own properties.